# Why isn't my JavaScript Login not functioning correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have been trying to solve this for hours and i have no idea how to do it - I have given up.

> Can someone please have a look at the code below and figure out what
>   is wrong with it please?

The idea of the program is to allow users to enter their Username and Password and when successfully verified then they are redirected to a URL. I think it is the Javascript which is not working properly
Here is the code:

```
 <html>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, 
pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;}

fieldset, img {border:0}

ol, ul, li {list-style:none}

:focus {outline:none}

body,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

html{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testbox {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 343px; 
  height: 464px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  background-color: #ebebeb; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
}

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

form{
  margin: 0 30px;
}

label.radio {
    cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 35px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label.radio:before {
  background: #3a57af;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

label.radio:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.25em;
    background: transparent;
    top: 7.5px;
    left: 4.5px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

hr{
  color: #a9a9a9;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

input[type=text],input[type=password]{
  width: 200px; 
  height: 39px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 13px; 
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=password]{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #3a57af;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 0px #cbc9c9;
}

.gender {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.accounttype{
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a.button {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 25px 0px 20px;
  margin: 10px 8px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px; height: 27px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: #3a57af; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; 
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a.button:hover {
  top: 3px;
  background-color:#2e458b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none; 
  box-shadow: none;

}

</style>
<body>
<div class="testbox">
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <form action="/">
      <hr>
    <div class="accounttype">
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioOne" name="account" checked/>
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio" chec>Student</label>
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioTwo" name="account" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Teacher</label>
    </div>
  <hr>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-envelope "></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="userid" id="name" placeholder="Username / Email"/>

  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="insid" id="ins" placeholder="Institution Code"/>

  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
  <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pass" placeholder="Password"/>

  <div class="gender">
    <input type="radio" value="None" id="male" name="gender" checked/>
    <label for="male" class="radio" chec>Primary</label>
    <input type="radio" value="None" id="female" name="gender" />
    <label for="female" class="radio">Secondary</label>
   </div> 
   <p>By clicking Login, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
   <a class="button"  onClick="check(this.form)">Login</a>
  </form>
  <script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
 if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
  {
    window.open('www.google.com')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please move your CSS to either a different file or completely remove it from the code block? It takes up a lot of space.

Comment: This isn't for School. This is for a website which i am setting up. I know this isn't the most effective way to setup a Login but it's a way i can manage easily.

Comment: For the record, if the password you're looking for is inside your code, you need to hide your code better, or anyone can look up the password with just pressing F12.

Comment: `a` elements don't have `form` property, only form control elements have that property. This, (and the missing bracket) is easy to find if you just would do the basic debugging ...

Answer (score 0):

Several issues.

- You need to close the brace of the `check` function.
- As mentioned by Teemu, a hyperlink doesn't have reference to the form, so you probably have to use a input type button or other input element. If you want to keep a hyperlink, use querySelector or some other method to grab the userid and password input fields.
- The hyperlink might not work. Depending on how you host this site, you might want to add `http://` in front of the link.

After changing those 3 things, the page works on my pc.
If you plan to use this login for something serious, do find a better system.
If you put the user names and passwords in the front end code, anyone can login as any user.